# JFrame and actionlistener jpanel

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

In the main class's constructor i have this actionlistener attached to a button:

```
home.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Home homepage = new Home();
        homepage.setBounds(0, 100, 500, 400);
        add(homepage);

    }
});
```

This is the Home class:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Home extends JPanel{

    public Home(){
        JButton jb = new JButton("Back");
        add(jb);
    }
}
```

The jb button doesn't show up on the jframe... can you help me out?

EDIT: It's actually there but you need to mouse over it to see it ... how can we request focus? like i do jb.requestFocus() and you still need to mouse over it.

Comment: try a `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Whether the JFrame is Set to visible? Have you add the Jpanel to the Frame ? Where  is that part of Code?

Answer (score 1):

When adding components dynamically, you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()`

```
   add(homepage);
   revalidate();
   repaint();
```

---

Side Note: Have a look at [Laying out Components withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn how to use layout managers. They are preferred over using null layouts, as you are doing.